# Submit button from imported php file doesn't validate data

Tags: joomla

I am using joomla and i wanted to add a new functionality to a joomla componnent. So i designed a php file called roomdetails.php that contains some textboxes and a submit button. The submit button validates the textboxes first and then saves data into the database.
I saved that php file in the joomla root folder and whenever i navigate to localhost/mywebsitename/roomdetails.php and click on the submit button, i can see that it properly validates the data. I haven't tested if it saves the data.
But Anyways, i imported the php file (roomdetails.php) to the joomla components php file and i can see the textboxes on the components front end form.

```
<?php include 'roomdetails.php'; ?>
```

But when i click the submit button now, it redirects me to the joomla administration index page. It doesn't even validate the data. what should i do?

P.S  i wrote the import statement just below the joomla component's  tag.

```
</form>
<?php include 'roomdetails.php'; ?>
```

When i use the import statement above the joomla component's  tag the submit button doesn't even do anything, not even re-direct.

```
<?php include 'roomdetails.php'; ?> 
</form>
```

Comment: Do you see anywhere else in Joomla where a file is included in that way? 
You need to use the Joomla API and patterns.

Comment: No i didn't see any import statement, i also tried to write the php code manually into the joomla component's code. It was the same thing.

Comment: Well how about doing the importing of files the way Joomla does instead? That's what I'm saying. Joomla has structured ways that it includes files, that's what you should do. For example you could look at jimport().  More likely however, you should just make a form plugin to modify the existing form.

Comment: I guess the solution was to put the php files in the root directory of the site's administrator folder, because that's where the submit button re-directs me.

Comment: WHy not just either use jimport or register a jLoader?